# How to reload angular directive/components on dropdown change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing a solution on everything is based an user option.

An user can have 3 profiles. Based on that selection, X,Y and Z should reload/update with new data based on that profile.

The page remains the same, only X, Y and Z should reload.
How can I do this? How can I make those "elements" reload after any change?

[image]

Comment: I'd say, use `$rootScope.$emit` on change of dropdown and attach listener in each of controller..

Comment: I think this will help your [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/ftfish/KyEr3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified solution can be something along this approach:

```
app.directive('x', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {
      $rootScope.$on('profile:changed', function(event) {
        scope.template = event.data.templateUrl;
      }
    }
    template: '<div ng-include="template">'
  }
});
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.choseTemplate = function(template) { //fire when dropdown selection changed
    $scope.emit('profile:changed', {templateUrl : template});
  };
});
```

Comment: I've read somewhere that its not recommended using "link" feature. Is that right?

Comment: According to the documentation: when you don't need to expose the controller to other directives, use link function. you can omit the "element" variable if you don't need it though. And of course, you can use the controller if you wish.

Comment: I've ended up using components, but it is very similar to your example directive. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Is your dropdown generated via a `<select>` tag?  If so you can use this method:

```
<select ng-options="item as item.name for item in items" 
 ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="update()"></select>
```

And then when a new selection is picked your update function will fire and you can update.

```
$scope.update = function() {
     $scope.item = //your code
}
```

Comment: you are not even using component in your answer